# Knockout.js save to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, knockout.js

Currently I am working on a survey application that uses django and knockout.js. I would like it to save the survey results to django but do not know how to pass the data to my views.py. Below is an example survey.

```
Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";

var surveyJSON = {pages:[{name:"page1",questions:[{type:"checkbox",choices:["apples","oranges","grapes"],name:"1",title:"What fruit do you like?"}]}]}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
    //send Ajax request to your web server.
    alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(s.data));
}

var survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJSON, "surveyContainer");
survey.onComplete.add(sendDataToServer);
```

Comment: You can `POST` the data to whichever view in your `views.py` file handles that incoming data.  You can `POST` it from a `<form>` or you can use AJAX, as long as you're targeting the URL for the proper view.

Comment: Great how do I post in knockout?

Comment: an example would be helpful

Comment: Here's some info about it from the [Knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).  You can also use a simple HTML `<form>` `POST` the same way you would without Knockout.